# WebRTC replaceTrack won't work for audio unless I replace video too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, videochat, mediastreamtrack

I am building a Video Chat app with WebRTC. Basicly, users exchange SDP and ICE candidates over Node.js socket server. Users exchange dummy video and audio tracks initially, then replace the tracks as users toggle their audio and video. Users are able to toggle their videos initially, then add audio without an issue. The problem is, you cannot share audio initially. For some reason, audio won't work without the video along with it.

**Here is the flow :**

1. All users connect to WebSocket server upon loading page.
2. Existing users send SDP offer to new comers and exchange ICE candidates using socket server
3. Existing user sends a dummy video and audio track unless they are already sharing video/audio
4. Newcomer sends dummy video and audio along with answer (they can't be sharing upon joining)
5. When a user shares their audio or video, replaceTrack replaces the corresponding video or audio

- I can share video without an issue ✅
- I can share video, then add audio without an issue ✅
- I cannot share audio initially ❌
- I can share audio first even thought it doesn't work, then add video and audio starts working too ✅

RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack() seems to be only working once video is also replaced. I am going nuts over this for a month now.

**When others join :**

```
    socketObj.current.on("userJoined", (data) => {
      addUser(data);

      //Establish peer connection
      if (data.userid != myUserID.current) {
        const establishPeerConnection = async () => {
          var peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }],
          });
          console.log("Creating new peer connection");

          //Transfer ICE Candidates
          peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
            if (event.candidate !== null) {
              socketObj.current.emit("peerData", {
                sender: myUserID.current,
                target: data.userid,
                type: "ICE",
                data: event.candidate,
              });
              console.log("Sent ICE Candidate (Initiator)");
            }
          });

          //Handle incoming stream tracks
          peerConnection.addEventListener("track", async (event) => {
            console.log("Incoming track!!! (initiator)");
            console.log(
              event && event.track && event.track.kind && event.track.kind
            );

            let foundConnection = activePeerConnections.current.filter(
              (x) => x.userid == data.userid
            );
            if (foundConnection && foundConnection.length) {
              if (foundConnection[0].stream) {
                //There is already a stream for this person, lets update the tracks
                if (event.track.kind == "video") {
                  activePeerConnections.current.forEach(
                    (eachConnection, index) => {
                      if (eachConnection.userid == data.userid) {
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].stream =
                          new MediaStream([
                            event.track,
                            activePeerConnections.current[
                              index
                            ].stream.getAudioTracks()[0],
                          ]);
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].streamID = uuid();
                      }
                    }
                  );
                } else if (event.track.kind == "audio") {
                  activePeerConnections.current.forEach(
                    (eachConnection, index) => {
                      if (eachConnection.userid == data.userid) {
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].stream =
                          new MediaStream([
                            activePeerConnections.current[
                              index
                            ].stream.getVideoTracks()[0],
                            event.track,
                          ]);
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].streamID = uuid();
                      }
                    }
                  );
                }
              } else {
                //We are adding the first track to this peers stream
                if (event.track.kind == "video") {
                  activePeerConnections.current.forEach(
                    (eachConnection, index) => {
                      if (eachConnection.userid == data.userid) {
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].stream =
                          new MediaStream([event.track, silence()]);
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].streamID = uuid();
                      }
                    }
                  );
                } else if (event.track.kind == "audio") {
                  activePeerConnections.current.forEach(
                    (eachConnection, index) => {
                      if (eachConnection.userid == data.userid) {
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].stream =
                          new MediaStream([black(), event.track]);
                        activePeerConnections.current[index].streamID = uuid();
                      }
                    }
                  );
                }
              }
            }
          });

          activePeerConnections.current.push({
            userid: data.userid,
            peer: peerConnection,
            stream: null,
            streamID: uuid(),
          });

          let foundMyVideo = activeVideos.current.filter(
            (x) => x.userid == myUserID.current
          );
          if (foundMyVideo && foundMyVideo.length) {
            //We are already streaming video, lets send that to the new comer
            console.log("ALREADY STREAMING");
            foundMyVideo[0].stream
              .getTracks()
              .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track));
          } else {
            console.log("NOT STREAMING, SENDING DUMMY INITIALLY");

            let dummyStream = blackSilence();
            dummyStream
              .getTracks()
              .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track));

            console.log("Created dummy stream, lets add it");
            console.log(dummyStream);
          }

          //Create offer
          let offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
          //Set local description
          await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
          console.log("Set local description : ");
          console.log(peerConnection);

          //Transfer SDP
          socketObj.current.emit("peerData", {
            sender: myUserID.current,
            target: data.userid,
            type: "SDP",
            data: offer,
          });

          console.log(data.username + " has joined, sending SDP...");
        };
        establishPeerConnection();
      }
    });
```

When toggling audio :

```
//User clicked toggle audio button
  const handleToggleAudio = () => {
    if (!socketConnected) return;
    if (!socketObj.current) return;
    if (!myUserID.current) return;
    if (!navigator) return;

    if (audioEnabled) {
      //User is trying to stop the audio, lets see if audio has started yet
      let getMyStream = activeVideos.current.filter(
        (x) => x.userid == myUserID.current && x.stream
      );
      if (!getMyStream) return;
      if (!getMyStream.length) return;

      //Replace our tracks here..
      activePeerConnections.current.forEach((eachConnection) => {
        eachConnection.peer.getSenders().forEach((eachSender) => {
          if (eachSender.track.kind == "audio") {
            eachSender.replaceTrack(silence());
            console.log("Replaced with dummy " + eachSender.track.kind);
          }
        });
      });

      //Stop the audio track
      getMyStream[0].stream
        .getTracks()
        .forEach((track) => track.kind == "audio" && track.stop());

      //If video stays, replace audio with silence  in activeVideos
      if (videoEnabled) {
        activeVideos.current.forEach((eachVideo, index) => {
          if (eachVideo.userid == myUserID.current) {
            let existingVideo = activeVideos.current[index].stream
              .getTracks()
              .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "video");
            activeVideos.current[index].stream = new MediaStream([
              existingVideo, //existing video
              silence(), //silence
            ]);
          }
        });
      } else {
        //Otherwise, remove the activeVideo completely
        activeVideos.current = [
          ...activeVideos.current.filter(
            (eachStream) => eachStream.userid != myUserID.current
          ),
        ];

        //Remove video reference from the video ref list
        videoRefs.current = videoRefs.current.filter(
          (eachRef) => eachRef.getAttribute("data-userid") != myUserID.current
        );
      }

      //Trigger re-render of video elements
      setAvUpdate((prevData) => prevData + 1);

      //Broadcast to all users that our audio has stopped via socket server
      socketObj.current.emit("audioStopped", {
        userid: myUserID.current,
      });

      setAudioEnabled(0);
    } else {
      //Start user audio, broadcast it
      setAudioEnabled(1);
      if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
          .then(function (stream) {
            let audioTrack = stream
              .getTracks()
              .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "audio");
            if (!audioTrack) return;

            //Replace our audio tracks with connected users here..
            activePeerConnections.current.forEach((eachConnection) => {
              eachConnection.peer.getSenders().forEach((eachSender) => {
                stream.getTracks().forEach((eachStreamTrack) => {
                  if (
                    eachSender.track.kind == eachStreamTrack.kind &&
                    eachStreamTrack.kind == "audio"
                  ) {
                    console.log(eachSender.replaceTrack(eachStreamTrack));
                    console.log("Replaced " + eachSender.track.kind);
                  }
                });
              });
            });

            //If video exists, add the audio to activeVideos so we can stop it later or stream to newcomers
            let foundVideo = 0;
            activeVideos.current.forEach((eachVideo, index) => {
              if (eachVideo.userid == myUserID.current) {
                foundVideo = 1;
                let existingVideo = activeVideos.current[index].stream
                  .getTracks()
                  .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "video");
                activeVideos.current[index].stream = new MediaStream([
                  existingVideo, //existing video
                  audioTrack, //new audio
                ]);
                activeVideos.current[index].streamID = uuid();
              }
            });

            //If there is not an active video stream, user is starting the audio first, therefore push it to activeVideos
            if (!foundVideo) {
              activeVideos.current.push({
                userid: myUserID.current,
                stream: stream,
                streamID: uuid(),
              });
            }

            //Trigger re-rendering of video boxes
            setAvUpdate((prevData) => prevData + 1);

            //Broadcast it
            socketObj.current.emit("audioStarted", {
              userid: myUserID.current,
            });
          });
      }
    }
  };
```

When toggling video :

```
//User clicked video button
  const handleToggleVideo = () => {
    if (!socketConnected) return;
    if (!socketObj.current) return;
    if (!myUserID.current) return;
    if (!navigator) return;

    if (videoEnabled) {
      //User is trying to stop the video, lets see if video has started yet
      let getMyStream = activeVideos.current.filter(
        (x) => x.userid == myUserID.current && x.stream
      );
      if (!getMyStream) return;
      if (!getMyStream.length) return;

      //Replace our tracks here..
      activePeerConnections.current.forEach((eachConnection) => {
        eachConnection.peer.getSenders().forEach((eachSender) => {
          if (eachSender.track.kind == "video") {
            eachSender.replaceTrack(black());
            console.log("Replaced with dummy " + eachSender.track.kind);
          }
        });
      });

      //Stop the video track
      getMyStream[0].stream
        .getTracks()
        .forEach((track) => track.kind == "video" && track.stop());

      //If audio stays, replace video with black in activeVideos
      if (audioEnabled) {
        activeVideos.current.forEach((eachVideo, index) => {
          if (eachVideo.userid == myUserID.current) {
            let existingAudio = activeVideos.current[index].stream
              .getTracks()
              .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "audio");
            activeVideos.current[index].stream = new MediaStream([
              black(), //new video
              existingAudio, //existing audio
            ]);
          }
        });
      } else {
        //Otherwise, remove the activeVideo completely
        activeVideos.current = [
          ...activeVideos.current.filter(
            (eachStream) => eachStream.userid != myUserID.current
          ),
        ];

        //Remove video reference from the video ref list
        videoRefs.current = videoRefs.current.filter(
          (eachRef) => eachRef.getAttribute("data-userid") != myUserID.current
        );
      }

      //Trigger re-render of video elements
      setAvUpdate((prevData) => prevData + 1);

      //Broadcast to all users that our video has stopped via socket server
      socketObj.current.emit("videoStopped", {
        userid: myUserID.current,
      });

      setVideoEnabled(0);
    } else {
      //User is trying to share his video
      setVideoEnabled(1);
      //Attempt to get video stream from mediaDevices
      if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
          .then(function (stream) {
            let videoTrack = stream
              .getTracks()
              .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "video");
            if (!videoTrack) return;

            //Replace our video tracks with connected users here..
            activePeerConnections.current.forEach((eachConnection) => {
              eachConnection.peer.getSenders().forEach((eachSender) => {
                stream.getTracks().forEach((eachStreamTrack) => {
                  if (
                    eachSender.track.kind == eachStreamTrack.kind &&
                    eachStreamTrack.kind == "video"
                  ) {
                    eachSender.replaceTrack(eachStreamTrack);
                    console.log("Replaced " + eachSender.track.kind);
                  }
                });
              });
            });

            //Also find our activeVideo stream and update the video track,
            //so when a new user joins, we can send this from stored stream or later stop tracks
            let foundVideo = 0;
            activeVideos.current.forEach((eachVideo, index) => {
              if (eachVideo.userid == myUserID.current) {
                foundVideo = 1;
                let existingAudio = activeVideos.current[index].stream
                  .getTracks()
                  .find((eachTrack) => eachTrack.kind == "audio");
                activeVideos.current[index].stream = new MediaStream([
                  videoTrack, //new video
                  existingAudio, //existing audio
                ]);
                activeVideos.current[index].streamID = uuid();
              }
            });

            //If there is not an active audio stream, simply add our stream to activeVideos
            if (!foundVideo) {
              activeVideos.current.push({
                userid: myUserID.current,
                stream: stream,
                streamID: uuid(),
              });
            }

            //Trigger re-rendering of video boxes
            setAvUpdate((prevData) => prevData + 1);

            //Broadcast to other users that our video has started
            socketObj.current.emit("videoStarted", {
              userid: myUserID.current,
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    }
  };
```

Dummy video and audio generating functions :

```
var silence = () => {
    let ctx = new AudioContext(),
      oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
    let dst = oscillator.connect(ctx.createMediaStreamDestination());
    oscillator.start();
    return Object.assign(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0], { enabled: false });
  };

  var black = ({ width = 640, height = 480 } = {}) => {
    let canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {
      width,
      height,
    });
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    let stream = canvas.captureStream();
    return Object.assign(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], { enabled: false });
  };

  var blackSilence = () =>
    new MediaStream([black({ width: 640, height: 480 }), silence()]);
```

Comment: Ever figure this one out?